# memcpy to copy integer to BYTE array

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm trying to send some data command in BYTE format to a serial port. Say I need to send ucXmtdat[60] buffer with message type set at offset 0, time value set at offset 1 to 4 and message number set at offset 5 to 9. To implement this actual in code can I go by below approach?

```
BYTE ucXmtdat[60];
ucXmtdat[0] = 0x0A;

int timeValue = 290920932;
memcpy(ucXmtdat+1, &timeValue, sizeof(int));

int seqNumber = 1;
memcpy(ucXmtdat+5, &seqNumber, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: It might work if the size of `int` is four bytes in both programs, and both programs are running on systems using the same [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Did you actually *try* it? What happened then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yeah, both are running on same system with same configuration.

Comment: @user2079303: Can you show a quick example what you are saying?

Comment: @hypheni whoops deleted my comment. I said why not use `sizeof(int)` for the offset like you do for the memcpy parameter, and here's the example: `memcpy(ucXmtdat+1+sizeof(int), &seqNumber, sizeof(int));`

Comment: @user2079303: well, that I kept simple in terms of readibility and macthing with requirement specification.

Comment: I would specify the width of `int` here explicitly by using a type: `int8_t, int16_t, int_32t`, then if numeric value you wanted to send was longer than this I'd break it down into the smaller size explicitly.